# How to select specific value in a Query in HTML <script>

Tags: javascript, html

I need to know how to select a specific value in a form of a query.
Under the `Content.join('');`, I need to select like 2 values which is the **Hello** and **Lorem ipsum...** then **Hi** and **Nullam fringilla...**, and so on.

Sorry, kinda new to this stuff as well.

```
   <script>
        var Count = 0;
        var title = document.getElementById("getTitle");
        var desc = document.getElementById("getDescription");
        var Content = [
            ["Option1", "Hello", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"],
            ["Option2", "Hi", "Nullam fringilla imperdiet eleifend"],
            ["Option3", "Greetings", "Cras dapibus ipsum a consequat tincidunt"]];
                
                    function previewImg(DibsSrc){
                    document.getElementById("Dibs").src =DibsSrc.src;
                    Content[Count][0] = DibsSrc.id;
                    title.innerhtml = Content.join('');
                    desc.innerhtml = Content.join('');
                }
    </script>
```

Comment: title.innerhtml = Content[Count][1]

Answer (score 0):

`Content[0][1]` or `Content[Count][1]` = Hello

`Content[0][2]` or `Content[Count][2]` = Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

To check the next item you need to update the `Count` var with a +1.

`Content[1][1]` or `Content[Count][1]` = Hi

`Content[1][2]` or `Content[Count][2]` = Nullam fringilla imperdiet eleifend

**Note that the count starts with 0, so your first item is 0 instead of 1.**